# Loop not automatically running in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a GUI where I can turn on a loop, but when I start my loop it's not automatically running. In this case it's not automatically printing "Test". I first have to click on the Check Variable option

I tried moving the code up and down but it doesn't work

```py
# import tkinter
from tkinter import * 

# 1 = on
# 3 = off
# Define Default variable 
global x
x = 3

# Window preferences
root = Tk()

# Change Variables
def changeVar1():
    global x
    x = 1

def changeVar2():
    global x
    x = 3

def printVariable():
    print(x)

#  loop
    while x < 2:
        print ("Test")
# Buttons 
button_1 = Button(root, text="Start", command=changeVar1)
button_2 = Button(root, text="End", command=changeVar2)
button_3 = Button(root, text="Check variable", command=printVariable)

# Button Posistion
button_1.pack()
button_2.pack()
button_3.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, the loop is within the `printvariable` callback function. When _should_ it be executed instead?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use after method, and don't create while loop inside tkinker main loop, because main loop will handle this.

=^..^=

```
from tkinter import *

x = 6
root = Tk()

def changeVar1():
    global x
    x = 1

def changeVar2():
    global x
    x = 3

def printVariable():
    print(x)

# Buttons
button_1 = Button(root, text="Start", command=changeVar1)
button_2 = Button(root, text="End", command=changeVar2)
button_3 = Button(root, text="Check variable", command=printVariable)

# Button Posistion
button_1.pack()
button_2.pack()
button_3.pack()

# set timer delay for after method
time_delay = 100  # should by > 0

def task_function():
    if x < 2:
        print("test")
    # repeat after method
    root.after(time_delay, task_function)

# set after method
root.after(time_delay, task_function)

root.mainloop()
```